# How to make a fixed div element with css ?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I need to create `div` element that would always be at the top right corner above all other elements

Here is what I tried

```
<div id="prompt" style=" height:50px;  width:50px;  background: #F00;  position: fixed;  top: 150px;    margin-left: 948px; z-index: 9999">Test</div>
```

I need it to work with `IE8` , but it is not working.

Comment: What specifically is not working? The "fixed-ness"? The positioning? The `z-index`?

Comment: Are you still on screen. set margin and top to "0" for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `left: 0;` or use `right` without `margin-left`.

Answer (score 1):

For positioning in the top-right corner:
`<div id="prompt" style="height:50px; width:50px; background: #F00;  position: fixed; top: 150px; right: 0; z-index: 9999">Test</div>`

Change the right value as you see fit (i.e. if you want the element an equal distance from the top as it is from the right, make the right value `150px`)

Answer (score 1):

By removing `margin-left: 948px;` and adding `right: 0px;`, your `#prompt` div will position itself on the right side of the screen in IE 8 and in major browsers as well I believe (Firefox confirmed).