# How to make a div element fixed?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I need my `<div> with id=prompt1` to be fixed and on top of all other elements . So that whenever I scroll the window, I can still see that `<div>` . In my `html` i does not work . (**IE8**)

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function() {
for (i=0; i<30; i++) {
$("#test").append("<TABLE border='solid'>" + 
   "<TR>" + 
      "<TD>Data 1</TD>" + 
      "<TD>Data 2</TD>" + 
   "</TR>" + 
   "<TR>" + 
      "<TD>Data 3</TD>" + 
      "<TD>Data 4</TD>" + 
   "</TR>" + 
"</TABLE>"); 
}
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body> 
<div id='test' style="float: left; width: 100px;" ></div> 
<div id="prompt1" style="float: left; width: 200px; height:50px; width:50px; background: grey; color: white;  position: fixed; top: 150px; right: 0; z-index: 9999">Prompt1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT**

The right answer is to add `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` at the top of the page

Comment: You already have a question very similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203970/how-to-make-a-fixed-div-element-with-css

Comment: doesn't work in what way?

Comment: When I scroll down the window, that `<div id=prompt1 . . ` becomes not visible . It stays where it was . I need it to be visible when I scroll the window

Comment: @Lee In that question, I did not post the full `html` so I did not get a good answer . I tried to delete it, but it did not let me

Comment: Then you should have edited the first question, rather than start a new one, as one of them will probably end up getting closed anyway.

Comment: but this question has nothing in it about showing a element on scroll??

Comment: By the way, I put your code into jsfiddle and the prompt div was perfectly fixed, and remained throughout all scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 8 does funny things with `fixed` - check out [Position fixed and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193255/position-fixed-and-internet-explorer), or google "ie8 position:fixed"

Comment: Thanks the right answer is there: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Answer (score 2):

Your code works. The `div` is just moved to the right. Depending on the resolution - you might not see it.

The key attribute is just `position=fixed`